# Nothing happens when I try to generate a key

Tags: github, ssh

I'm trying to generate a key for my computer, but I notice that when I try running the command that I see on GitHub.com, nothing happens, and I only get a prompt. I'm wondering what could be happening? Advice is appreciated, thanks!

I tried searching up how to generate an SSH key, and it seems that I'm supposed to be getting a different output. I tried going into different directories but got the same issue.

Edit: Adding text output, since I can't seem to produce an image.

[username]$  ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C “[Github email]"

(Output): ">"

Answer (score 1):

One of your quote symbols is the wrong type of quote symbol - specifically, it's U+201C LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK.  Re-type the command - it was probably messed up by copying it from somewhere.

If your shell prompts you with a >, that means you are not done entering your command yet.  Try typing something simple like

```
echo "test
```

Bash will display a > and wait for you to finish the command.  In this case it's because you've opened a quote (the last character in your command) and not yet closed it.

Comment: This was it!! My quotation sign was wrong. I had copied it from somewhere but when I typed it out myself, it worked. Thanks so much!

Comment: And the comment about shell was insightful too-- thanks!

Comment: You're welcome :) Mark it as answered if it helped you!